# my mybatis not work for Oracle but tested it work in SQLDeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle, mybatis

I'm new to Mybatis, I create a mapper to get the timestamp I want. but only one period of time it works, but later it just returns null. and for another function, I using SimpleDateFormat to format date into "dd-MMM-yyyy hh.mm.ss.SSS a", so I can insert it into timestamp(3) of the Oracle database.
Below is my code, any suggestions?

```
@Select("SELECT MAX(TIME_STARTED) FROM METADATA_SYNC_LOG WHERE STATUS = 'SUCCESSFUL'")
Date getLastSyncStartedTime();

@Insert("INSERT INTO METADATA_SYNC_LOG (ID, SERVICE, HOST, TIME_STARTED, TIME_FINISHED, STATUS, SYNCRESULT) values (#{ID}, #{SERVICE}, #{HOST}, #{TIME_STARTED}, #{TIME_FINISHED}, #{STATUS}, #{SYNCRESULT})")
void insertIntoMetadata_Sync_log(@Param("ID") String id, @Param("SERVICE") String service, @Param("HOST") String host, @Param("TIME_STARTED") String time_started, @Param("TIME_FINISHED") String time_finished, @Param("STATUS") String status, @Param("SYNCRESULT") String syncresult);

@Update("MERGE INTO SERVICE_METADATA d USING (SELECT #{SERVICE} SERVICE, #{ID} ID, #{SERVICE_ENTITY} SERVICE_ENTITY, #{TIME_CREATED} TIME_CREATED, #{TIME_FINISHED} TIME_FINISHED, #{DETAILS} DETAILS FROM dual) s ON (d.ID = s.ID) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET d.SERVICE = s.SERVICE, d.SERVICE_ENTITY = s.SERVICE_ENTITY, d.TIME_CREATED = s.TIME_CREATED, d.TIME_FINISHED = s.TIME_FINISHED, d.DETAILS = s.DETAILS WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (SERVICE, ID, SERVICE_ENTITY, TIME_CREATED, TIME_FINISHED, DETAILS) VALUES (s.SERVICE, s.ID, s.SERVICE_ENTITY, s.TIME_CREATED, s.TIME_FINISHED, s.DETAILS)")
void insertOrUpdateIntoService_Metadata(@Param("SERVICE") String service, @Param("ID") String id, @Param("SERVICE_ENTITY") String service_entity, @Param("TIME_CREATED") String time_created, @Param("TIME_FINISHED") String time_finished, @Param("DETAILS") String details);
```

Comment: If `getLastSyncStartedTime()` returns `null`, the query returns `null`. You should enable [logging](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html) to verify (be sure to set log level to `TRACE`).

Comment: this query can fetch the correct timestamp in SQLDeveloper. But it can not fetch by Mybatis.

Comment: Please add the TRACE log output to the question.

Comment: org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Opening JDBC Connection
org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Setting autocommit to false on JDBC Connection
[my function] - ==>  Preparing: SELECT MAX(TIME_STARTED) FROM METADATA_SYNC_LOG WHERE STATUS = 'SUCCESSFUL'
[my function]  - ==> Parameters: 
[my function]  - <==      Total: 1
org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Resetting autocommit to true on JDBC Connection
org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Closing JDBC Connection

Comment: Um...that seems like a DEBUG level (TRACE includes the result value). Could you provide an executable repro like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues)? It would save both of our times a lot.